# Singular or plural (ensures)?

Tags: plural-forms, singular

In this quote, should it be *ensure* or *ensures*?

> Comprehensive experience in all aspects of entertainment and media law in combination with exceptional people and project management skills **ensures** excellence at every level.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is ensure.

While longer, you are essentially saying [A] and [B] ensure [C].

[Scroll to "Compound Subject"](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/moduleSVAGR.htm)

Comment: The subject is "comprehensive experience", therefore, it's "ensures". But it is a very messy and poorly written sentence.

Comment: *Comprehensive* **experience** *[in all . . .]* **ensures**  . . .

Comment: I disagree, it's a compound subject, albeit awkward: "Comprehensive experience in all aspects of entertainment and media law--in combination with (aka AND)--exceptional people and project management skills ensure excellence at every level."

Answer (score 0):

For easier understanding, the sentence can be re-written as:

> ... **experience** ... **ensure(s)** excellence... **in combination with** ... people ... and ... skill ...

Since the subject is "experience", the verb must be in singular: **"ensures"**.

However, the original sentence is definitely not a model on how to use English properly. While correct, it is difficult to understand. Until you have enough words to have a meaning, one already forgets the beginning.

Comment: "in combination with" is another way of saying "and". It's a compound subject and therefore it agrees with third person plural.